# ReadAsArray leaves Qgs in unstable state

Tags: gdal

I have a QGIS plugin that reads a raster to get the elevation at vertex points in a polyline.  The issue is that even though a single call to ReadAsArray(...) appears to work, if I immediately exit QGIS, A Crash Dump dialog appears. What is wrong with the way I making the call?

```
def run(self):   
# show the dialog
self.dlg.show()
# Run the dialog event loop
result = self.dlg.exec_()
# See if OK was pressed
if result:
    selectedVectorLayer = self.getSelectedVectorLayer()
    selectedRasterLayer = self.getSelectedRasterLayer()
    if self.validateSelectedLayers(selectedVectorLayer,selectedRasterLayer) is False:
        return;         
    gdal.AllRegister()        
    ds = gdal.Open(selectedRasterLayer.source(), GA_ReadOnly)
    if ds is None:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(selectedRasterLayer.source() + ' not found!', 'LineSlopes', QgsMessageLog.WARNING) 
        return   
    dataPoint = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(122, 149, 1, 1)
    del ds
```

Comment: Based on other forum comments, I thought possible culprits were 1. faulty installation of GDAL.  or 2.  The size of the raster was much too large.

Comment: On my windows 10 x64 machine I made sure to un-installed all instances of GDAL, bindings and python and QGIS, then I cleaned out all references to GDAL from my paths.  I then reinstalled only QGIS.  Still same problem.  I then clipped the raster down to the minimum rectangluar size that include the lines.  Still the same problem.  I'm out of ideas as to what could be causing this.  I also can't believe that this is a GDAL library problem.

Comment: Please, I will try any suggestion, this is a show stopper for me.  I can't use QGIS if something like ReadAsArray leaves it in an unstable state!  Oh, I can duplicate this on my laptop, and also with a different raster.

Comment: I tried uninstalling my 64 bit version of QGIS and installed the 32 bit version instead.  Doesn't help.  Get the same crash.